# Tkinter Listbox set focus on last item

Tags: listbox, tkinter

How do I select the last item in my Tkinter Listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call `selection_clear()` to remove any existing selection, followed by `selection_set("end")` [2] to select the last element. You might want to also call `see("end")` to make sure it has been scrolled into view.